# How can I change header in request and pass it to another IP

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I want to change header of request and change destination IP and pass it to the correct destination.
How can I do it by flask and python.
This is my header

```
Host: 10.1.3.127:5000
Accept-Encoding: identity
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
Content-Length: 0
X-Amz-Date: 20191110T122830Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=yasin1/20191110/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=08610e134c60ffdfe3b4d8159d740b398b38565d0d38481cb405739bc401adea
User-Agent: Boto3/1.10.2 Python/2.7.12 Linux/4.4.0-142-generic Botocore/1.13.2 Resource
```

I want to change Host to 10.1.3.41:8080 and make requset to this destination.

Comment: Is this a real valid `Authorization` header?

Comment: yes . it is for s3 amazon in ceph

Comment: It was not the smartest move to post it here.

Comment: It is in my lab and no one access it.